# GCC 4.9.2 cross-compiler build for ARM

Tags: c++, gcc, android-ndk

I am trying to build a cross-compiler for ARM.  When I add c++ to my "enable-languages" list in the configure (see) below, the gmake errors out with:

```
checking for exception model to use... 
  configure: error: unable to detect exception model
  gmake[1]: *** [configure-target-libstdc++-v3]
```

but when I take c++ out of the "enable-languages", as in my configure script below, the GCC cross-compiler builds just fine.

```
 ../gcc-4.9.2/configure --prefix=/home/me/ANDROID21 --target=arm-linux-androideabi 
   --with-gmp=/home/me/ANDROID21 --with-mpfr=/home/me/ANDROID21 
   --with-mpc=/home/me/ANDROID21 
   --with-gnu-as--with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,fortran --disable-nls 
   --disable-tls 
   --disable-bootstrap --disable-libgomp --disable-shared --disable-libssp 
   -disable-libquadmath --enable-threads --enable-target-optspace --disable-libatomic 
   --with-sysroot=/home/me/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-arm
```

For reference, here is my machine info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux (system name) 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 16 01:56:35 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And the GCC I'm building off of:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/me/GCC4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/me/gcc-4.9.2/configure --prefix=/home/me/GCC4.9.2 --disable-multilib 
  --enable-libgomp --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)
```

Any ideas on possible causes?

Haven't found anything definitive in the archives yet. Would really like to get the c++ portion to cross-compile too.

TIA,
Steve

Comment: take a look to https://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk for inspiration

Comment: Thanks for that link.  I did try pointing my "with-sysroot" in my configure to that ndk, but did not get any farther.